# Visual Resource(s) for android.R.*?

Tags: java, android, android-source

I'm trying to find a website or a list of websites that I can reference when trying to integrate some of the built-in Android resources into my applications and I'm wondering what everyone else uses.

For instance, I want to find a site that lists all the different animations in "android.R.aim" and shows what each animation does to a view/layout/etc (by visual examples... e.g. before and after images for each animation). Or maybe another site that shows what each style in "android.R.style" looks like when applied to a layout with different types of views.

So far I have only been able to find a visual reference for the items in "android.R.drawable": http://darshancomputing.com/android/1.5-drawables.html

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answer to all you questions, but:

- http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/ provides a visual reference for android 2.0
- As far as I can see you can find the images available at this location in the android source
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi

Comment: Thank you very much. Those links are quite helpful.